# Passing a string containing HTML as argument in VueJS doesn't work?

Tags: vuejs2

I'm trying to create a mixin where I can pass string and the mixin do some changes and return the modified string to be outputed.

It works well with basic string, but as soon as I put HTML on it, it stops working.

Here's a working example of my issue: https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/98267/

And here's the HTML:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h1>{{ test("This works!") }}</h1>
  <p>{{ test("This<br />doesn't work!") }}</p>
</div>
```

And the JS:

```
Vue.mixin({
    methods: {
    test: function (message) {
        return message
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to escape the special characters like "<".

If you don't know how this can be done, you can use this online tool: https://www.freeformatter.com/html-escape.html

```
This<br />doesn't work!
```

will be converted to

```
This&lt;br /&gt;doesn't work!
```

Comment: This returns the escaped value, so the html is useless after that :/

Answer (score 0):

Edited: The double mustaches interprets the data as plain text, not HTML. So, use **v-html** directive. Example is here https://jsfiddle.net/jfopfpwo/

```
<div id="app">
  <h1>{{ test("This works!") }}</h1>
  <p v-html="test(`This <br />doesn't work!`)"></p>
</div>

Vue.mixin({
methods: {
test: function (message) {
    return `${message} (:`
   }
 }
})
new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data: {
     message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
   }
})
```

BTW, u made some sort of filters, that r already in Vue. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html

Comment: Thanks, but I need to have the text not in data, but in the html, called in a function. Is this possible?

Comment: Vue is not a string-based templating engine, you should prefer [components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html) and composition. Furthermore, dynamically rendering arbitrary HTML on your page can be dangerous and open your website up to [XSS Vulnerabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)